# Reindex for i18n Translations with searchkick and globalize combination

Tags: elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

I am using following two gems in my rails application:

- https://github.com/ankane/searchkick
- https://github.com/globalize/globalize

I have i18n translations globalize gem installed in my rails application with following models:

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
    translates :description, :name
    searchkick
end
```

with attributes id, created_at and updated_at

```
class ServiceTranslation < ApplicationRecord
end
```

with attributes id, service_id, locale, name, created_at and updated at

I use Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS in my server. My elasticsearch version is 2.3.1 in ubuntu and searchkick version is 3.0.2 in rails application.

While I reindex my model Service in service model using searchkick method Service.reindex, I got following error:

Service Import (377.4ms) {"count":29,"exception":["Searchkick::ImportError","{"type"=\u003e"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=\u003e"failed to find type parsed [keyword] for [name]"} on item with id '1'"],"exception_object":"{"type"=\u003e"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=\u003e"failed to find type parsed [keyword] for [name]"} on item with id '1'"}
Searchkick::ImportError: {"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to find type parsed [keyword] for [name]"} on item with id '1'
from (irb):1

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Searchkick 3 only supports Elasticsearch 5+. If you can't upgrade Elasticsearch, use Searchkick 2.5.

```
gem "searchkick", "~> 2.5"
```